# OroCRM how filter with extend entiey field?

Tags: orocrm

I added dynamically an extra field to Contact entity, and i would like to perform a query filter on that field. When i added to my DQL it through an Exception.

How can i filter with that extra field ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the official guide on [creating an extended entity field](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities/extend-entities/#id1).

If you already managed to create and run the migration and the new field appeared in a database, but it's not accessible from the code, you can try to run below command to warm up all the application caches

```sh
php bin/console oro:platform:update
```

Comment: I managed to work with auto-generated Contact entity class from cache, but i need to   rework it as it mentioned in official docs.